# Pandas Is Not Reading_csv Raw Data When Names Are Defined in a Second Line

Tags: python-3.x

I just started my first IRIS FLOWER project based on your example. After completing two projects, I will move to the next step, statistical and deep learning. Of course, before that I will get your book and study it.
Despite, I faced with error in my first project. The problem is I couldn't load/read the data from online or from my local computer. My computer is equipped with all necessary modules (find an attachment).

I applied the same procedure you illustrated in your example. My system read the data only when I removed the name definitions from the second line, which is `names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']`.

When I deleted the definitions of the names, from the coding, pandas read_csv file directly from online and also it read from the local computer. But, the retrieved data has no heading (field) at the top. 
When I tried to read the data with the name definitions in the second line, it gives the following error message:

> NameError: the name 'pandas' is not defined

How I can deal with this problem?

```
#Load dataset

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/iris.csv"

names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']

dataset = pandas.read_csv(url, names=names)
print(dataset)
```

Comment: Have you imported pandas.? Like `import pandas` .?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you put `import pandas as pd` in your imports. Use `pd.read_csv()` instead. If you didn't import `pandas`, then you need to import it at the top of your Python file with `import pandas` or `import pandas as pd` (which is what pretty much everyone else uses).

Otherwise, your code looks fine.